# Disabling ng-click on this element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I [have](http://codepen.io/N1kbes/pen/GNRxRg) three buttons in one controller with ng-click functions. How I can disable click when this element is already clicked?
Here is example:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="GreetingController">
    <button ng-click="!IsClickEnable||DoSomethingElse()">xyz</button>
    <button ng-click="!IsClickEnable||DoSomethingElse()">xyz</button>
    <button ng-click="!IsClickEnable||DoSomethingElse()">xyz</button>
  </div>
</div>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('GreetingController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.IsClickEnable = true;
  $scope.DoSomethingElse = function() {
    alert('click')
    $scope.IsClickEnable = false;
  };

}]);
```

Comment: you wan't to disable each button after it is clicked?

Comment: @NicolasGarnil yes. Now it`s disable all buttons.

Comment: You only need to use `ng-disabled`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('GreetingController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.DoSomethingElse = function(event) {
    event.target.disabled = true;
  };

}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="GreetingController">
    <button ng-click="DoSomethingElse($event)">xyz</button>
    <button ng-click="DoSomethingElse($event)">xyz</button>
    <button ng-click="DoSomethingElse($event)">xyz</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('GreetingController', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {

    $scope.buttons = [{
      "name": "xyz",
      "disabled": false
    }, {
      "name": "xyz",
      "disabled": false
    }, {
      "name": "xyz",
      "disabled": false
    }];

    $scope.DoSomethingElse = function(b) {
      console.log("Do something");
      b.disabled = true;
    }
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="GreetingController">
    <button ng-repeat="button in buttons" 
            ng-disabled="button.disabled" 
            ng-click="DoSomethingElse(button)">
      {{button.name}}
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is way too much code to just disable a button.

Comment: @Targaryen That is why you downvote it ? I try to propose an alternative without handling DOM element. This is working

Comment: It is `ng-disabled` (not ng-disable) and that is all you need

Comment: @Targaryen: As you yourself stated in Rambler 's answer, the property needs to be stored in the controller. Weedoze is doing exactly that--one for each button. Don't be that guy.

Comment: @Weedoze: the array and `ng-repeat` is a bit excessive though. Get rid of them.

Comment: @AlvinThompson I am using it to disable only one button after clicking it. How can do it without the array and without using DOM event or element ?

Comment: @Weedoze OK. That is fair if you want to disable 1 button at a time.

Comment: @Targaryen Thanks... That's what OP asked. Please remove the downvote now

Comment: I am able to upvote now that you fixed the errors. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just add nd-disable directive to your buttons :

```
 <button ng-click="clicked=true;DoSomethingElse()" ng-disabled-"clicked">xyz</button>
```

A javascript independent solution.This way you need not care about setting the flag in your controller.Just add `clicked=false` at the init of your controller.

Comment: In this case, the button will not be clickable again at a later time. The `clicked` variable needs to be stored in angular.

Comment: Yeah the `clicked=false` initialization will take care of it in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

A better way to do this is by writing a custom directive that updates the DOM element using jqLite or jQuery (in-case the jQuery library is loaded). Check the below code snippet.

The DOM shouldn't be updated in the Controller because it inhibits unit testing and DOM manipulations should happen in the directive, to justify in this scenario as the buttons are created in the view itself and not generated using the data in the Controller.

```js
angular
  .module('demo', [])
  .controller('GreetingController', GreetingController)
  .directive('disableOnClick', disableOnClick);

GreetingController.$inject = ['$scope'];

function GreetingController($scope) {
  $scope.doSomethingElse = function() {
    console.log('do something else');
  }
}

function disableOnClick() {
  var directive = {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: linkFunc
  }

  return directive;

  function linkFunc(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
    element.on('click', function(event) {
      event.target.disabled = true;
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demo">
  <div ng-controller="GreetingController">
    <button disable-on-click ng-click="doSomethingElse()">xyz</button>
    <button disable-on-click ng-click="doSomethingElse()">xyz</button>
    <button disable-on-click ng-click="doSomethingElse()">xyz</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: OP asked for Javascript not JQuery

Comment: @Weedoze, my code snippet doesn't use jQuery. AngularJS comes with a cut-down version of jQuery built into it called as jqLite, using jqLite's API I've mapped a click event on the buttons to disable them